# SQL request output the largest number of the previous month

Tags: mysql, sql

My schema:

[image]

I have:

```
doctors
id name             profession 
 1 James Harden     dental 
 2 James Jones      therapist 
 3 LeBron James     cardiologist 
 4 Kobe Braynt      surgeon 
 5 Sabrina Williams nurse 
 6 Tyler Okonma     speech therapist 
 7 John Snow        pediatrician

patients 
id name         diagnostic 
 1 Mo Bamba     tooth pulling out
 2 Kaney West   astma 
 3 Post Malone  heart attack 
 4 Denzel Curry headache 
 5 Nicola Jokic stomac-ache 
 6 Dwayne Wade  AIDS 
 7 Boo Aby      headahce

visits
doctorId  patientId  visitDate
1           1         2019-03-09
2           4         2019-03-01
2           5         2019-02-26
2           6         2019-02-05
3           3         2019-02-13
4           2         2019-03-07
7           1         2019-02-14
7           7         2019-02-15
```

**I need to print the doctors serving the *largest number* of patients for the previous month.**

My request is:

```
select d.name, g.counter
from doctors d inner join (
  select doctorid, count(distinct patientid) counter
  from visits
  where 
    year(visitdate) = year(current_date - interval 1 month)   -- return cur. year
    and 
    month(visitdate) = month(current_date - interval 1 month) -- return prev. month
  group by doctorid
  order by counter
) g on g.doctorid = d.id
order by g.counter desc, d.name
```

results from my request:

```
   name        counter
   James Jones    2
   John Snow      2
   LeBron James   1 <- wrong
```

I need to output only like this:

```
       name        counter
       James Jones    2
       John Snow      2
```

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag.  The code is not SQL Server.  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff     sorry, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following gets the visits per doctor for the previous month:

```
select doctorid, count(distinct patientid) as counter
from visits v
where visitdate >= (curdate() - interval day(visitdate) - 1 day) - interval 1 month and
      visitdate < (curdate() - interval day(visitdate) - 1 day
group by doctorid;
```

Next, you need the top values.  In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions.  This is harder in older versions.  One method is a `having` clause:

```
select doctorid, count(distinct patientid) as counter
from visits v
where visitdate >= (curdate() - interval day(visitdate) - 1 day) - interval 1 month and
      visitdate < curdate() - interval day(visitdate) - 1 day
group by doctorid
having count(distinct patientid) = (select count(distinct v2.patientid) as cnt
                                    from visits v2
                                    where v2.visitdate >= (curdate() - interval day(v2.visitdate) - 1 day) - interval 1 month and
                                          v2.visitdate < curdate() - interval day(v2.visitdate) - 1 day)
                                    group by v2.doctorid
                                    order by cnt desc
                                    limit 1
                                   );
```

Getting the name and other information is just a question of joining in other tables, which you seem to know how to do.

Comment: I don't get why I have `Unknown column 'month' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I think `day(month)` is supposed to be `day(visitdate)`

Comment: @GordonLinoff          Argh.. I am trying to check your updates, I have still only one returning row.  It argues on group , I think, I need to put  `(` -> `visitdate <`  `(` `curdate()`. Sorry, need your help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff        Could you help, please?